# Canvas scrolling up when it shouldn't

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a `canvas`

```py
canvas = tk.Canvas(app, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, bg=style.background)
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
```

I have a scrollbar in that `canvas`

```py
def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    # Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(app, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
main_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas: onFrameConfigure(canvas))
```

and I set the up and down keys to scroll up and down.

```py
app.bind("<Down>", lambda event: canvas.yview_scroll(1, "units"))
app.bind("<Up>", lambda event: canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units"))
```

---

The problem is, when a scrollbar in a `canvas` is disabled, I can scroll **up** more then I should be able to scroll up (with `canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units")`). 
[image]

It should be like this and not let me scroll up unless there is something up to scroll too.
[image]
*It should stay like this even if I do `canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units")`, it still shouldn't scroll up like in the first image*

Or like this, when the scrollbar is active, I can't scroll up.
[image]
*If I do `canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units")`, nothing would happen since I'm already on the top. I want this to happen by the first case too (when the scrollbar is not active).*

---

Basically, I want by a `canvas` without an active scrollbar (because there's nothing to scroll to), the widgets in the canvas stay on the top (and it won't allow you to scroll with `canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units")`).
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Not your whole code, something created specifically for this question.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ok, I edited the question.

Comment: You still haven't given us a [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley You want the whole code at once as a minimal reproducible example? I thought you meant the images. I'm sorry, I'll put a minimal reproducible example of the whole code.

Comment: _"You want the whole code at once as a minimal reproducible example?"_ **No** we do not want the whole code. We need a _minimal_ amount of code that accurately reproduces the problem. I can't imagine it would take more than a dozen or two lines. we need a canvas, an illustration of how you're adding things to canvas, and how you've created the scrollbars and how and when you update the `scrollregion` attribute. Please follow this link and read it: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: Canvas scrolling up when it shouldn't

This happens when the `scrolledregion=` was lesser than the parent, here `app`, of the canvas.

You are using:

> - [`bbox(item=None)`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.bbox-method)
>     Returns the bounding box, as a 4-tuple, for all matching items.

The `bbox` can be lesser if **no** item or **all** items fit the parents `height`.

---

**Solution**:

Verify, before applying `scrolledregion=` that the `bbox`, here the `height` value, is `>=` than the `height` of the parent.

```
def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    # Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame
    bbox = self.canvas.bbox("all")
    x, y, width, height = bbox
    if height < self.canvas.winfo_height():
        bbox = x, y, width, self.canvas.winfo_height()

    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=bbox)
```

Obey the note from

> - [Tkinter.Canvas.bbox-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.bbox-method)
>     the bounding box is approximate and may differ a few pixels from the real value